# Share single post comment from wordpress to facebook

Tags: html, wordpress, comments

quick question. i want to add a "share" button to each comment so that it would be possible to share a single comment with its content on facebook. 
i've already setted up my own comments.php with callback function for custom html. 
so it's already possible to echo all the comments stuff (url, author, date etc.) but when it comes to sharing, facebook always crawls the post content. try to add the sharing button with open graph facebook html and with the addanyshare plugin as well. no success. is there a special plugin for that i've missed?

if u guys need any additional info, please let me know.

thanks for your help in advance.

best
michael

functions.php - added this for custom html and added shortcode for social media plugin

```
function mytheme_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
if ( 'div' === $args['style'] ) {
    $tag       = 'div';
    $add_below = 'comment';
} else {
    $tag       = 'li';
    $add_below = 'div-comment';
}?>
<<?php echo $tag; ?> <?php comment_class( empty( 
$args['has_children'] ) ? '' : 'parent' ); ?> id="comment-<?php 
comment_ID() ?>"><?php 
if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) { ?>
    <div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body"> 
<?php
} ?>
    <?php 
    if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) { ?>
        <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your 
 comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?></em><br/><?php 
    } ?>


    <?php comment_text(); ?>   
    <?php echo do_shortcode("[TheChamp-Sharing]"); ?>

    <div class="comment-author vcard">- <?php 
        if ( $args['avatar_size'] != 0 ) {
            echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); 
        } 
        printf( __( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span 
 class="says">says:</span>' ), get_comment_author_link() ); ?> / <?php
            /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
            printf( 
                __('%1$s'), 
                get_comment_date()
            ); ?>
       </div>
    <div class="share"> 



    </div>
    <div class="reply"><?php 
            comment_reply_link( 
                array_merge( 
                    $args, 
                    array( 
                        'add_below' => $add_below, 
                        'depth'     => $depth, 
                        'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ); ?>
    </div><?php 
if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
    </div><?php 
endif;
}
```

comments.php

```
<?php wp_list_comments( 'type=comment&style=div&callback=mytheme_comment' ); ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You'll need to post code if you want to get any help here.

Comment: sorry justin. just added some code snippets. thanks!